# How to make tests for a service which is consuming another service with a Repository<entity>

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

As the title says, I'm having issues creating tests for an auth.service which is pretty simple. But When I ran the tests I keep getting the following error:

```
   TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
        --> starting at object with constructor 'NestContainer'
        |     property 'modules' -> object with constructor 'ModulesContainer'
        |     property 'InternalCoreModule' -> object with constructor 'Module'
        --- property 'container' closes the circle
        at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

This is how my code looks:

```
//auth.service.spec.ts
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { jwtConstants } from './strategies/constants';
import { JwtStrategy } from './strategies/jwt.strategy';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        UsersModule,
        PassportModule,
        JwtModule.register({
          secret: jwtConstants.secret,
          signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService, 
        JwtStrategy,
        UsersService
    ],
    }).compile();

    service = moduleRef.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

```
//auth.service.ts
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Users } from '../db/entities/users.entity';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export class User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(
    username: string,
    password: string,
  ): Promise<Users | undefined> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      user?.passwordHash,
    );

    if (isPasswordCorrect) {
      return user;
    }
    return null;
  }

  async login(userRequest: any) {
    const response = await this.validateUser(
      userRequest.username,
      userRequest.password,
    );

    if (response && response !== undefined) {
      const payload = {
        username: response?.userName,
        sub: response?.id,
      };

      return {
        access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
      };
    }

    throw new NotFoundException(
      'This combination of user and password does not exist.',
    );
  }
}
```

```
//users.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Users } from '../db/entities/users.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users)
    private userRepository: Repository<Users>,
  ) {}

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<Users | undefined> {
    return this.userRepository.findOneBy({
      userName: username,
    });
  }
}
```

I think that I have to mock the userRepository for UsersServices at my auth.services.spec.ts file somehow, but I really don't know how. Any kind of help or guidance is well appreciated :)

I had a similar issue at my users.service.spec.ts tests, but that was easier to fix, as the only thing I had to do was to add the following at the providers section:

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing the `JwtModule` and `UsersModule` module, and adding those services to the `providers`, your test shouldn't import any modules and should create mocks for providers other than the one you are testing, so that you have total control over the testing environment in your unit tests. [This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) has a lot of testing examples that show how you can make the [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) mocks.

That error you are receiving was a bug from the new errors Nest was throwing and should also be resolved now, by the way.